# Number of Dyck paths with maximal odd sequence of $(1,-1)$ ending on the $x$-axis

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

> A Dyck path from $(0,0)$ to $(2n+2,0)$ is a lattice path with steps
>   $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$, never falling below the $x$-axis.
>
> Find the number of Dyck paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n+2,0)$ such that any
>   maximal sequence of consecutive steps $(1,-1)$ ending on the $x$-axis
>   has odd length.

The above question is from Richard Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics. In fact, a solution is given by Stanley, but I am not sure why we should proceed like that.

> Let $A(x)=x+x^3+2x^4+6x^5+\cdots$ (respectively,
>   $B(x)=x^2+x^3+3x^4+8x^5+\cdots$) be the generating function for Dyck
>   paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n, 0)$ such that the path only touches the
>   $x$-axis at the beginning and end, and the number of steps $(1,-1)$ at
>   the end is odd (respectively, even).

**How do we obtain these two generating functions? Why does it suffice to consider the paths that touch the $x$-axis at the beginning and the end?**

> Let $C(x)=1+x+2x^2+5x^3+\cdots$ be the generating function for all
>   Dyck paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,0)$. Note that the coefficients are
>   Catalan numbers. It is easy to see that $A=x(1+CB)$ and $B=xCA$.
>   Solving for $A$ gives $$A=\frac{x}{1-x^2C^2}.$$

Although I may not understand how to come up with $A$ and $B$, this part is simply computation.

> The generating function we want is $$\frac{1}{1-A}.$$

**I again do not understand this part. Why do we have such a generating function?**

> The above simplifies to $1+xC$, which means that the required number
>   follows the Catalan numbers.

Any help for the above question is appreciated.

Comment: here a closed form for generating function of the Catalan's numbers http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%281-2x-%E2%88%9A%281-4x%29%29%2F%282x%5E2%29+at+the+origin

Comment: @janmarqz : The generating function $C(x)$ refers to the Catalan numbers, this part I get it. My greatest problem is $A(x)$ and $B(x)$.

Comment: Note that $A(x)=x+x^2\frac{d}{dx}(xC(x))$

Answer (score 1):

> **Approach:** The idea is to analyse specific types of Dyck paths which can be used as *building blocks* and to find *generating functions* for them. These generating functions will be used to specify the generating function we are actually looking for.

We put the focus on Dyck paths of length $2n$, starting at $(0,0)$ and ending at $(2n,0)$ which *do not touch* the x-axis between the start and end point. The number $n$ specifies the number of up steps which is equal to the number of down steps.

It is convenient to *split* these Dyck paths in paths which end with an odd number of down steps and those which end with an even number of down steps.

> **Generating functions A(x) and B(x)**
>
> Let's denote the generating function with an odd number of terminating down steps $A(x)$. In order to get a first impression of this function we look for the number of Dyck paths counted by $A(x)$ for small lenghts  $2n$.
>
> In the following we encode up steps with *u* and down steps with *d*. So, all paths counted by $A(x)$ start with an $u$ and end with an odd sequence of $d$'s.

- $n=2$: We get one path $\color{blue}{ud}$
- $n=4$: We get no path, since $udud$ touches the $x$-axis between start and end point and $uudd$ does not end with an odd sequence.
- $n=6$: We consider the pattern $\color{blue}{u(..)ddd}$ and obtain one path $\color{blue}{uuuddd}$.
- $n=8$: We consider the pattern $\color{blue}{uu(..)uddd}$. Since we have to start with two $u$'s in order to not touch the $x$-axis in between and we have due to the same reason to terminate with three $d$'s, which implies that there is an up step $u$ before them. We find the paths $\color{blue}{uu(ud)uddd}$ and $\color{blue}{uu(du)uddd}$.
- $n=10$: We consider the path $\color{blue}{uuuuuddddd}$  and the pattern $\color{blue}{uu(....)uddd}$  giving $1+\left(\binom{4}{2}-1\right)=6$ Dyck paths. Note, that we have to exclude $uu(dduu)uddd$ to not touch the $x$-axis in between.

> We conclude
>
> \begin{align*}
>    A(x)=x+x^3+2x^4+6x^5+\cdots
>    \end{align*}
>
> With similar reasoning we can find the first coefficients of the generating function $B(x)$ counting all Dyck words which do not touch the $x$-axes in between and which terminate with an *even* number of down steps.
>
> \begin{align*}
>    B(x)=x^2+x^3+3x^4+8x^5+\cdots
>    \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **Relationship $A(x),B(x)$ with $C(x)$:**
>
> We denote with $C(x)$ the generating function of the *[Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)* $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$
>   \begin{align*}
>   C(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_nx^n=\frac{1}{2x}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4x}\right)
>   \end{align*}
>   The coefficients $C_n$ give the number of *all Dyck paths* of length $2n$.
>
> Let's look at the expression
>
> \begin{align*}
>   C(x)A(x)&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_nx^n\right)\\
>   &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}C_kA_{n-k}\right)x^n
>   \end{align*}

If we consider e.g. the coefficient of $x^4$ we see
\begin{align*}
  C_0A_4+C_1A_3+C_2A_2+C_3A_1+C_4A_0
  \end{align*}

So, the coefficient of $x^4$ specifies the number of all Dyck paths $C_k$ of length $k\, (0\leq k \leq 4)$ *concatenated* with all specific Dyck paths $A_{4-k}$.

> We conclude: The multiplication $C(x)A(x)$ specifies the number of *all Dyck paths* which terminate with an odd sequence of down steps. Note, here are also Dyck paths which touch the $x$-axis thanks to the left multiplication with $C(x)$ and the termination by an odd number of down steps is guaranteed by the multiplication with $A(x)$.
>
> It follows, that
>   \begin{align*}
>   B(x)=xC(x)A(x)
>   \end{align*}
>   since the multiplication with $x$ represents a starting up step $u$ and an ending down step $d$. This guarantees that we end with an *even* number of down steps and it is also assured, that we *do not touch* the $x$-axis in between.
>
> With a similar reasoning we see that
>   \begin{align*}
>   A(x)=x+xC(x)B(x)
>   \end{align*}
>   whereby the summand $x$ represents the Dyck path $\color{blue}{ud}$.

$$ $$

> **Concatenation of building blocks:**
>
> If we consider the geometric series
>
> \begin{align*}
>   G(x)=\frac{1}{1-A(x)}=1+A(x)+A^2(x)+A^3(x)+\cdots
>   \end{align*}
>
> we can think of $A^k(x)$ as counting the concatenation of $k$ Dyck paths each terminating with an odd number of down steps.
>
> We observe that each $A^k(x)$ counts Dyck paths, which touch the $x$-axis between start and end point, $k-1$ times. So,  the geometric series $G(x)$ provides us with *all Dyck paths* of the wanted shape.

Comment: For $G(x)=\frac{1}{1-A(x)}$, does $A^k(x)$ count the concatenation of $k$ Dyck paths each of which touches the $x$-axis only at the two ends, and terminates with an odd number of down steps? The question asks for paths that any *maximal* sequence of consecutive steps $(1,-1)$ ending on the $x-$axis is odd. So, $A^3(x)$ consists of 3 odd paths, but it could be odd, even, odd, and the odd one is the longest, right?

Comment: I checked $n=4$ and the $14$ wanted paths do not include uuuddduudd and uudduuuddd. So, I guess in the question "maximal" should be removed.

Comment: @HaoranChen: The notion *maximal sequence of consecutive steps $(1,-1)$* does not address a maximal sequence of the complete path, but instead maximal with respect to *runs* of consecutive steps. If we had odd, even, odd this implies the *maximal* sequence of the middle sequence has even maximal length which is not admissible. See example 6.19 in vol 2. of Enumerative Combinatorics by R. P. Stanley.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @HaoranChen: You're welcome. :-)